# Can you pass a variable into the interval of DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, datediff

I have a feeling I already know the answer but can you do the following (most basic example)

```
DECLARE @interval varchar(2) = 'yy'

SELECT DATEDIFF(@interval, myDate, GETDATE())
```

I'm holding the unit (yy, mm or dd) in a column and want to dynamically run DATEDIFF based on one of the other columns, passing through the interval.

Comment: **[`The datepart value cannot be specified in a variable, nor as a quoted string like 'month'.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You need to use a `case` expression:

```
select (case @interval
            when 'year' then datediff(year, mydate, getdate())
            when 'month' then datediff(month, mydate, getdate())
            when 'day' then datediff(day, mydate, getdate())
        end)
```

I should say.  You *could* use dynamic SQL, but that is generally unnecessarily complicated for this type of calculation.

Comment: @Gordon, wouldn't it be `yy`, `mm`, `dd` per the `@interval varchar(2)`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA The variable is a string whose content and interpretation are determined by the code writer. Those values could be anything - 'day', 'd', 'jour', 'dia',  'lobster', etc. The better question is why you think to suggest using 'yy' vs 'year'. Is there a reason to make code less readable by using abbreviations?

Comment: @SMor, per OP, the values are kept in a column (yy, mm, dd). And the variable `@interval` was declared as `varchar(2)`, so `year, month, day` would not fit into a 2 character variable. That's all, nothing more. I respect @Gordon and his answers tremendously, so I was merely pointing out that the variable he is checking against, per OP, was 2 characters. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case @interval
            when 'yy' then datediff(year, mydate, getdate()) end as 'YEAR'
 case @interval
            when 'mm' then datediff(month, mydate, getdate()) end as 'MONTH'
 case @interval
            when 'dy' then datediff(day, mydate, getdate())end as 'DAY'
```

Make sure for Day, there is no keyword as 'dd' like for month 'mm'
Reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp